# Do Canon dSLRs have something like HDR, ADR, or iso expansion?

Tags: d-lighting, adr

I've just bought a Canon EOS 100D/SL1.

I was looking at this comparison and I'm not fully happy: http://www.dxomark.com/Cameras/Compare/Side-by-side/Canon-EOS-100D-versus-Nikon-D3300___871_928

However I was wondering if the latest SLR cameras by Canon have something like D-Lighting or similar functions.

[Why is Adaptive Dynamic Range incompatible with ISO Expansion?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2049/why-is-adaptive-dynamic-range-incompatible-with-iso-expansion)

Comment: I've found something: http://digital-photography-school.com/what-is-canons-auto-lighting-optimizer/

Comment: Most unclear question to selected answer ever. Asked for D-Lighting; AJ provided that. Selected answer doesn't even apply to camera in question. Great content here. -1.

Comment: I suspect the original poster is just somewhat confused as to what HDR, active D-lighting (auto lighting optimizer for the Canon folks), adaptive dynamic range (highlight tone priority) and ISO expansion actually do.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: but in someway compressing an image from 12 bit to 8 bit per channel means adjusting the curves. On the other side it can mean flattering the image or clipping it. Since this kind of conversion (from RAW to JPG can lead to lose some dynamic range I see a very small difference between HDR from 1 RAW to the final JPG and adjusting the curve (as D-Lighting I guess is doing) from RAW to JPG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for out of the box additional functionality like hdr, focus stacking etc, you may consider [Magic Lantern](http://www.magiclantern.fm/). It's a firmware add on for Canon Cameras.

Comment: However, ML is not maintained for the 100D/SL1 (i.e., no nightly builds). But yes, dual-iso mode and auto-ETTR in particular might help extend dynamic range if there ever is a build for the SL1.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, take DXoMark scores with a LARGE grain of salt.  They are regularly and thoroughly discredited as useless laboratory measures trying to simplify things that can't be easily simplified and have very little bearing on real world performance.  In particular, the low light performance is routinely found to be lower on Canons because of the way the tests are done, while looking at real world images, the Canons often beat the Nikons despite Nikons having a substantial "advantage" on DXoMark.

As for D-Lighting, yes, Canon's Auto Lighting Optimizer serves a very similar role and can be adjusted to multiple levels of impact.  Note that, if memory serves, both primarily impact JPEG processing. (D-lighting might have some impact on exposure, I don't know Nikon's system as well as Canon's.)  If you really want maximum control over lighting response, shoot RAW and handle your own processing.

Comment: I would also take a look at Highlight Tone Priority which is similar but different on Canon systems. ALO is the closest feature match on Canon to D-Lighting though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Canon DSLRs have a way of capturing HDR images, most though (the 5D Mark III has it for example) don't combine the photos in an HDR image, you'll have to do that yourself in post (also no correction for ghosting and such, of course).

Some of the more expensive DSLRs have ISO expansion. For example, my 60D goes to 6400 natively but when I turn ISO expansion on in the custom functions I'll 'unlock' the H1 setting (high 1) which is 12,800.

Canon cameras have a feature called Auto Lighting Optimizer instead of D-Lighting that is mostly made for processing of JPEG images, but to be honest, the difference isn't that noticeable. It's configurable in three modes I believe.

Comment: Not entirely true. At least Canon 5D Mk III has the possibility to make an HDR entirely in camera. The module provides also some options to tweak the process. (in fact it is an exposure fusion to be more precise).

Comment: You're right John, I forgot about that. I'll improve my answer